# Backbonejs - prevent router from listening to hash changes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

OK, this is a weird one, but I'm hoping to get ideas.
Is there a way to prevent a Backbone.Router from listening to hash changes?

I want to use the declarative functionality of the router - being able to declare a map of routes and handlers - but I don't want the router to trigger the handlers on hash change, rather when I specifically call it with a route expression.

The only way I found to call a router is by using:

```
router.navigate(route, {trigger:true});
```

but this actually changes the URL, which is something I don't want.

Alternatively, is there some other object in Backbone or Marionette which can give me this declarative functionality?

Comment: You should see the answer in your original question. You should really try not to make duplicate questions.

Comment: Hi @sQVe. After re-reading both questions, I can see why the look like duplicates. However, that wasn't my intent. They both stem from the same problem I'm working on and I was looking at the same issue from different angle. The fact that you pointed out to me that they ask the same question, leads me to understand that I actually have one problem to solve, not two. So thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
router.navigate(route, { trigger:false});
```

I did a test in my application and the routes I am sending through this call no longer work once I make this change.  I am still able to navigate in the application if I enter the route in the url and hit entry.